# ZeroMQ PUSH/PULL

Tags: c++, zeromq, publish-subscribe

Some part of `zmq` is not behaving in a predictable manner.

I'm using VS2013 and zmq 3.2.4. In order to not 'lose' messages in my pubsub framework [aside: I believe this is a design flaw. I should be able to start my subscriber first, then publisher and I should receive all messages] I must synchronise the publisher with the subscriber a la [durapub/durasub](http://zguide.zeromq.org/cpp:durapub) etc. I am using the durasub.cpp and durapub.cpp examples found in the zeromq guide. 
If I use the examples as-is, the system works perfectly.

If I now add scoping brackets around `ZMQ_PUSH` in durasub.cpp

```
{
    zmq::socket_t sync (context, ZMQ_PUSH);
    sync.connect(syncstr.c_str());
    s_send (sync, "sync");
}
```

the system stops working. The matching 'ZMQ_PULL' signal never reaches the application level in durapub.cpp.

I have stepped through the C++ wrapper to check the return values from `zmq_close` and all is well. As far as ZMQ is concerned it has delivered the message to the endpoint.
Hopefully I've done something obviously stupid?

There's more. The addition of

```
std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1));
```

allows the system (ie the pub/sub) to start working again. So it's clearly a race-condition, presumably in the reaper thread as it destroys the socket.

More digging around. I think LIBZMQ-179 refers to the problem as well.

---

***EDIT#2*** 2014-08-13 03:00 [UTC+0000]

Publisher.cpp:

```
#include <zmq.hpp>
#include <zhelpers.hpp>
#include <string>
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    zmq::context_t context(1);
    std::string bind_point("tcp://*:5555"); 
    std::string sync_bind("tcp://*:5554"); 
    zmq::socket_t sync(context, ZMQ_PULL);
    sync.bind(sync_bind.c_str());

    //  We send updates via this socket
    zmq::socket_t publisher(context, ZMQ_PUB);
    publisher.bind(bind_point.c_str());

    //  Wait for synchronization request
    std::string tmp = s_recv (sync);        
    std::cout << "Recieved: " << tmp << std::endl;          

    int numbytessent = s_send (publisher, "END");       
    std::cout << numbytessent << "bytes sent" << std::endl;
 }
```

Subscriber.cpp

```
#include <zmq.hpp>
#include <zhelpers.hpp>
#include <string>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{   
    std::string connectstr("tcp://127.0.0.1:5555"); 
    std::string syncstr("tcp://127.0.0.1:5554");    

    zmq::context_t context(1);

    zmq::socket_t subscriber (context, ZMQ_SUB);
    subscriber.setsockopt(ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, "", 0);
    subscriber.connect(connectstr.c_str());

#if ENABLE_PROBLEM
    {
#endif ENABLE_PROBLEM
        zmq::socket_t sync (context, ZMQ_PUSH);
        sync.connect(syncstr.c_str());
        s_send (sync, "sync");
#if ENABLE_PROBLEM
    }
#endif ENABLE_PROBLEM

    while (1) 
    {
        std::cout << "Receiving..." << std::endl;
        std::string s = s_recv (subscriber);
        std::cout << s << std::endl; 
        if (s == "END")
        {
            break;
        }
    }  
}
```

1. Compile each cpp to its own exe.
2. Start both exes (starting order is irrelevant)

**If `ENABLE_PROBLEM` is defined:**

- Publisher: (EMPTY prompt)
- Subscriber: 'Receiving...' 
  And then you have to kill both processes because they're hung...

**If `ENABLE_PROBLEM` is not defined:**

- Publisher: 'Received: sync'
  '3 bytes sent'
- Subscriber: 'Receiving...' 
  'END'

Comment: What happens if you manually set `ZMQ_LINGER` to -1?

Comment: @Jason - makes no difference. Manually setting ZMQ_LINGER=-1 does not help.

Comment: Alright, with the edits this is clearly C++ specific, as the scoping brackets don't change any ZMQ specific logic.  I've added that tag to your question so hopefully you can get better help.

Answer (score 0):

***EDIT#1*** 2014-08-11: Original post has changed, without leaving revisions visible

### What is the goal?

With all due respect, it is quite hard to isolate the goal and mock-up any PASS/FAIL-test to validate the goal, from just the three SLOC-s above.

So let´s start step by step.

### What ZMQ-primitives are used there?

T.B.D.

*post-EDIT#1*: **`ZMQ_PUSH`** + **`ZMQ_PULL`** + ( hidden **`ZMQ_PUB`** + **`ZMQ_SUB`** ... next time rather post ProblemDOMAIN-context-complete sources, best enriched with self-test-case outputs alike:

```
...
// <code>-debug-isolation-framing ------------------------------------------------
std::cout << "---[Pre-test]: sync.connect(syncstr.c_str()) argument" << std::endl;    
std::cout <<                              syncstr.c_str()            << std::endl;
std::cout << "---[Use/exec]: "                                       << std::endl;
sync.connect(                             syncstr.c_str());
// <code>-debug-isolation-framing ------------------------------------------------
...
```

)

### What ZMQ-context create/terminate life-cycle-policy is deployed?

T.B.D.

*post-EDIT#1*: n.b.: ZMQ_LINGER rather influences **`.close()`** of the resource, which may take way before a ZMQ_Context termination appears. ( And may block ... which hurts... )

### A note on "When does ZMQ_LINGER really matter?"

This parameter comes into action once a `Context` is near to be terminated, while a sending-queue is not empty yet and an attempt to `zmq_close()` is being handled.

In most architectures ( ... the more in low-latency / high-performance, where microseconds and nanoseconds count ... ) the (shared/restricted) resources setup/disposal operations appear for many reasons **either** at the very begining, **or** at the very end of the system life-cycle. Needless to tell more why, just imagine the overheads directly associated with all the setup / discard operations, that are altogether simply not feasible to take place ( the less to repetitively take place ... ) during routine flow of operations in near-real-time system designs.

So, having the system processes come to the final "tidy-up" phase ( just before exit )

setting `ZMQ_LINGER == 0` simply ignores whatever is still inside the **<*sender*>**'s queue and allows a prompt `zmq_close()` + `zmq_term()`

Similarly `ZMQ_LINGER == -1` puts whatever is still hanging inside the **<*sender*>**'s queue a label of **[*Having an utmost value*]**, that the whole system has to **wait ad-infimum**, after ( hopefully any ) **<*receiver*>** retrieves & "consumes" all the en-queued messages, before any `zmq_close()` + `zmq_term()` is allowed to take place ... which could be pretty long and is fully out of your control ...

And finally `ZMQ_LINGER > 0` serves as a compromise to wait a defined amount of [msec]-s, should some **<*receiver*>** comes and retrieves an en-queued message(s). However on the given TimeDOMAIN milestone, the system proceeds to `zmq_close()` + `zmq_term()` to a graceful clean release of all reserved resources and exit in accord with the system design timing constraints.

Comment: In light of the comments above, I've edited my post. The ZMQ primitives I'm concerned with are ZMQ_PUSH/ZMQ_PULL. This issue has nothing to do with ZMQ-context lifetime. I now understand that ZMQ_LINGER only interacts with ZMQ-context lifetime, and so I've removed any reference to ZMQ_LINGER in my post. Thanks.

Comment: The formatting of the answer can be improved extensively.